# Eclipse error in project, but i can't find it

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

While Developing an "hello world" app for my brand new htc desire, i found something strange.

I can't execute my programm, it says: "You can't do that with an error in your code" or something ;)

i know eclipse. normally eclipse show me where the error is, in which file exactly, but if i look to the project browser, i get that image:
http://img404.imageshack.us/i/unbenanntdpe.png/

and i just developed in 2 files:
http://pastebin.com/KfU2fH98

the error happend all off a sudden, can someone figure out what this mean?

thank you!

Comment: Just clean the project and try to run it again dude..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try cleaning it

```
Project -> Clean
```

then see if that works, has solved many of my problems

Comment: I had the same problem, but Clean did not fix it. Eclipse does kind of a poor job of providing errors by default, but if you open up the "Problems" pane (under Window -> Show View) you'll see more or less exactly what is causing the dreaded red x.

Comment: Was going to edit to add (but SO unfortunately restricts that): Once you resolve the problems there (mine was an expired debug certificate) a Clean should get rid of the red x for good.